# Force QWebView to download web page content in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwebview

How can i force QWebView into downloading the webpage and related content in a separate thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot easily.
You could implement your own QNetworkAccessManager (see createRequest()) that offloads the work to a QNetworkAccessManager in another thread.

What is your exact problem?
Maybe it can be solved differently or a bug to Qt can be reported?

Answer (score 2):

That's now the default behaviour so you can just relax and watch :)
See [Qt Earth Team Mix Feb 2011](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/25/qt-earth-team-mix-feb-2011/) and [Threading support for QNetworkAccessManager](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-14162)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you see a problem in having a QWebView loading content at the main thread? I mean, the main thread won't be locked at all if you do this.

You can have a hidden QWebView loading content and just when it has finished you show it.

Maybe you should describe your problem/idea a little bit more to help us help u.